# awk arithmetic operation from string

Tags: awk, operation

I have a specific column in a file which contains strings like this :

```
1.1*1024
1.0*1024
1.1*1024
...
```

I want the numeric result :

```
1126.4
1024.0
1126.4
```

So I tried this, please note that the sizes are on the 6th column of my file :

```
$ cat file | awk '{col=$6;size=sprintf("%f", col);print "=> col = "col" size = "size}'
=> col = 1.1*1024 size = 1.100000
=> col = 1.0*1024 size = 1.000000
=> col = 1.1*1024 size = 1.100000
```

EDIT1 My input file looks like this :

```
$ cat file 
[[  ]]  toto1.mp4  2019-04-16  22:11  1.1*1024
[[  ]]  toto2.mp4  2019-04-16  21:41  1.0*1024
[[  ]]  toto3.mp4  2019-04-16  22:40  1.1*1024
[[  ]]  toto4.mp4  2019-04-16  22:09  1.1*1024
...
```

Somehow the multiplication is ignored.

Can you help ?

Comment: @oguzismail The sizes are on the 6th column of my input file

Comment: @oguzismail I've just added an EDIT1

Comment: Is the arithmetic operation always `*` or could it sometimes be `+` or `/` or ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is generic way to to evaluate the string , it could process `*` ,`+`,`-`,`/` etc. If you can use `perl` then there is option to `eval` the string, this will evaluate the string for the math operation from the input.

**CASE-1:** When evaluating entire line:

```
cat inputfile
1+1
2*2
3/3
4.5*2
5/2

perl -nle ' print eval ' inputfile
2
4
1
9
2.5
```

**CASE-2:** When evaluating one column only: In this case 6th column. supply the column number to get evaluated, F[5] is the 6th column.

```
perl -nale  'print  eval  $F[5]' inputfile
1126.4
1024
1126.4
1126.4
```

**case-3:** When evaluating 6th column, but printing entire record. Evaluate 6th column and update its value, later print the whole line.

```
perl -nale  '$F[5] = eval  $F[5] ;print "@F"' inputfile
[[ ]] toto1.mp4 2019-04-16 22:11 1126.4
[[ ]] toto2.mp4 2019-04-16 21:41 1024
[[ ]] toto3.mp4 2019-04-16 22:40 1126.4
[[ ]] toto4.mp4 2019-04-16 22:09 1126.4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your perl one-liner, I love it. Now, I typed this to sum all the sizes which are on the 6th colum, is that OK : `perl -nale  '$size+=eval $F[-1] if /mp4/;END{print $size}' file` ?

Comment: yes, you can   do it , assuming you are sure that the string of interest is always in last column.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following(tested and written after seeing provided samples only).

```
awk '{split($NF,array,"*");printf("%.01f\n",array[1]*array[2])}' Input_file
```

Comment: The sizes are on the 6th column of my input file

Comment: @SebMa, but your samples show it is 1st and 2nd column if I consider field separator as `*`, please post your correct sample Input_file in your post and let us know then.

Comment: I've just added an EDIT1

Comment: Use `*` or space as field separator and use second last and last column: `awk -F '[* ]' '{printf("%.1f\n",$(NF-1)*$NF)}' file`

Answer (score 2):

`sprintf` can't evaluate operations itself. You need to parse and evaluate them, and then `sprintf` can be used for converting the result into a string with a specific format.

```
$ awk -v OFS='  ' 'split($NF,a,/\*/)>1{$NF=a[1]*a[2]} 1' file
[[  ]]  toto1.mp4  2019-04-16  22:11  1126.4
[[  ]]  toto2.mp4  2019-04-16  21:41  1024
[[  ]]  toto3.mp4  2019-04-16  22:40  1126.4
[[  ]]  toto4.mp4  2019-04-16  22:09  1126.4
```

Answer (score 2):

Awk can't evaluate expressions in variables, you need to build an evaluator for it or evaluate some other way, like:

```
$ awk '{
    cmd="awk \47BEGIN{print " $6 "}\47"  # prepare an external awk command 
    cmd | getline retval                 # execute
    print retval                         # output evaluated value
    close(cmd)                           
}' file
```

Output:

```
1126.4
1024
1126.4
1126.4
```

There are awk programs floating around that can evaluate, for example `calc3`. Google is your friend, my friend.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ awk -F'[[:space:]*]+' '{printf "%.1f\n", $(NF-1) * $NF}' file
1126.4
1024.0
1126.4
1126.4
```

Answer (score 0):

if data in `d` file, tried on gnu awk:

```
 awk -F'\\*' '{a=$1*$2; printf "%-6.1f\n",a}' d
```